# Lightning:inputField not retrieving the value in JS Controller?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

```
 <aura:component description="detail_page" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId"     controller="DetailController" access="global">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />    
    <aura:attribute name="Opportunity" type="Object" 
                    description="The record object to be displayed"/>
    <aura:attribute name="OpportunityRecord" type="Object" 
                    description="A simplified view record object to be displayed"/>
    <aura:attribute name="recordSaveError" type="String" 
                    description="An error message bound to force:recordData"/>
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String"/>
    <force:recordData aura:id="recordHandler" 
                      layoutType="FULL" 
                      recordId="{!v.recordId}"  
                      targetRecord="{!v.Opportunity}"
                      targetError="{!v.recordSaveError}"
                      targetFields="{!v.OpportunityRecord}"

                      mode="EDIT"
                    /> 

    <div aura:id="firstSection">                           
        <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="recordEditForm" 
                              objectApiName="Opportunity"
                              recordTypeId="{!v.recordId}">                            
             <lightning:inputField fieldName="Bank_Account_Number__c" value="{!v.OpportunityRecord.Bank_Account_Number__c}"/> 
       </lightning:recordEditForm>

     </div>
</aura:component>
```

JS Controller

```
saveRecord : function(component, event) {

        var action = component.get("c.updateOpportunityRecord");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(component.get("v.OpportunityRecord.Bank_Account_Number__c")));
        action.setParams({
            "opp": component.get("v.Opp")
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            console.log('state--'+state);            
            if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
                // component.set("v.opp", response.getReturnValue());
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);       
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(component.get("v.OpportunityRecord.Bank_Account_Number__c")));
```

The console logs shows the correct value when `lightning:input` or `ui:inputText` is used, but showss `undefined` when `lightning:inputField` is used.

How can I successfully use a `lightning:inputField`?

Comment: why are you using lightning:recordEditForm AND force:recordData? shouldnt you be using  lightning:recordEditForm ? additionally, lightning:recordEditForm will handle most of the logic for you, why do you need to call the server? which of your forms is triggering saveRecord?

Comment: Sorry @glls, I saved my edit just fractionally after yours... oh well :)

Comment: Because upon save I have to related Parent and child fields

Comment: aren't you able to use/reference 2x lightning:recordEditForm ?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a combination of [LDS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service.htm) and `ligthning:recordEditForm` in your code, which you should first **fix**. If you use `lightning:inputField` within a `ligthning:recordEditForm`, then you don't really need to provide the `value` attribute, just providing the `fieldName` will render the value there.

As to answer your question:

> How can I successfully use a lightning:inputField?

Once you fix your code to use the record edit form and input field appropriately, you need to assign an "id" to the input field and use that in your JS to retrieve its value. As an example, your input field becomes something as:

```
<lightning:inputField aura:id="bankAccountNumber" fieldName="Bank_Account_Number__c"  />
```

And then, access this in your JS to get the value as:

```
var bankAccountNumber= component.find("bankAccountNumber").get("v.value");
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I have to write multiple lightning:RecordEditForm as I have to update more than 40 fields (contains parent object fields as well ) upon clicking save button. How to do this?

Comment: You would need to post that as a different question. The one here specifically addresses what you have asked originally.